# Read Dynamically images from web/api (.net) in android

Tags: android, remote-server

how to read dynamically image from web in android, i have a method which takes String type url  and return drawable, i want to get an image from remote location and set it in my imageview and through remote location change to image occur and these change automatically reflect in my android application.
i have this code, any help will be appreciable, and thanks in advance

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url){
    try{
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable drw = Drawable.createFromPath(url2);
        //Drawable draw = Drawable.createFromStream(is, url2);
        return drw;


    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an external library like Picasso or Universal-Image-Loader. URLS:

- http://square.github.io/picasso/
- https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: can you share some example code using picasso, the link you provided for picasso, is little bit not understandable because i have never use this library

Comment: in github you have a sample application that will help you to understand how picasso works =)

Answer (score 1):

your code is a bad way to showing an remote image from url. it can caused your apps not responsive.
i recommend you to using some 'image loader library' which it is take the advantages of android asynchronous task and keep your apps responsive.

for example, you can use this library:
https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/releases/tag/0.26.8

all you need to do is import the library into your project, then load your image in just a view code:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
AQuery aq = new AQuery(this); // assume you are doing this inside activity
String someImageURL = "http://someurl.com/someimage.jpg";

aq.id(imgView).image(someImageURL, true, true); // see documentation for detail
```

Answer (score 0):

if u don't want to use tool or image loader library  and your application not interacting to internet continuously, Then
 you can take XML from server at ones, that containing  image url's list, parse the XML, and download  them one by one on sd card and show them offline by using ImageView.setImageResource(...) this process will make your app more faster and you can set time interval to check update from server.

If u have large no of images then u have to use image loader library because above process may cause memory space issue on device .